# Getting VS2017 to look for updates on the local network instead of the web

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to build a sustainable method for regularly updating VS2017 on a number of developer machines.

We already install directly from a network-based layout.

However, I would now like to stop machines getting version updates advertised within the VS2017 GUI from the web and get them instead from an updated network-based-layout.

I looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/controlling-updates-to-visual-studio-deployments?view=vs-2017. And tried to follow the steps there.

However, if I have a machine with 15.8.7, an updated network layout of 15.8.8 and the latest version on the web is 15.8.9, the GUI advertises 15.8.9 as the latest available to the end user. This seems wrong and it then seems it goes off to try and update from the web, even though I have made all the recommended changes to response.json to point to a network version of the channelmanifest.json document.

Has anyone successfully been able to get this type of arrangement working on their own network? If so, could they please share any advice which goes beyond that contained in the link above. I found that page to be particularly confusing: what job does the separate channel manifest file do? Why in their example is the channel manifest file actually in the same directory as the layout?

Thanks